# ngx-pagination doesn't works fine with Filtering table

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I got simple table where I implemented filtering option by `local_part` everything works fine until I am not trying to search into table when I am for exaple on the last page.
If I am on first page I can find everyting but when I for example on the 20th page it searching but I got blank rows ( and pagination shows that I got only 1 page ( so it's correct ) When I am clicking on my pagination [1] then I see filtered data)

For Filtering I am using `ngx-filter-pipe` and for pagination `ngx-pagination`

My input to searching into table

```
<input class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Szukaj aliasu" type="text [(ngModel)]="queryString.local_part">
```

My table row

```
<tr *ngFor="let aliases of alias | filterBy: queryString | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
```

My pagination controls

```
<pagination-controls 
  (pageChange)="p = $event" 
  directionLinks="true" 
  autoHide="false"
  responsive="true" 
  previousLabel="Prev" 
  nextLabel="Next">
</pagination-controls>
```

How should it be? I want to filter my table no matter which page I am on.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an ultimate solution, but in my project, I created a custom object as 'config' for declaring the pagination properties as a workaround:

```
this.config = {
  itemsPerPage: 6,
  currentPage: 1,
};
```

And now in the HTML change as following:

```
*ngFor="let service of services | filter:searchText | paginate: config"
```

on the input of the search bar just add click event as follows:

```
(click)="config.currentPage = 1"
```

It will look something like this:

```
<input matInput (click)="config.currentPage = 1" placeholder="Ex. City Data" #input [(ngModel)]="searchText">
```

This resolved my issue.